# Button onClick, Cycle through Colors/Backgrounds

Tags: android, android-studio, android-button

I am using Android Studio
I'm wanting to change the color of my button, with each click.
To cycle it through around 10 colors and start over again in a continuous loop.

For example I'm using `setBackgroundResource(@drawable/oval)`

```
oval = blue circle button  
oval2 = red circle button  
oval3 = green circle button and so on.
```

So far I have it that button1 starts as oval(blue) and onClick turns into oval2(red)
So my question is, how to add another click to change it to oval3(green) and then cycle it back to the start oval(blue)?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.shadowz.buttononclick;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
private Button colorChangeButton;
private TextView basicText;
private RelativeLayout background;

Button button1;
Button button2;
Button button3;
Button button4;
Button button5;
Drawable oval1;
Drawable oval2;
Drawable oval3;
Drawable oval4;
Drawable oval5;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
    basicText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    colorChangeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    // Code Break

    button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

    // Code Break

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v == button1) {
                button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval2);

            }
        }
    });
    // Code Break

    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v == button2) {
                button2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval3);

            }
        }
    });
    // Code Break
    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v == button3) {
                button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval4);

            }
        }
    });
    // Code Break
    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v == button4) {
                button4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval5);

            }
        }
    });
    // Code Break
    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (v == button5) {
                button5.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.oval6);

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.shadowz.buttononclick.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/backgroundLayout">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:text="button1"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:text="button2"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:text="button3"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:text="button4"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:text="button5"
    android:background="@drawable/oval"
    android:padding="@dimen/abc_action_bar_content_inset_material"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="78dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by following:

Create integer-array in resources:

```
<integer-array name="backgrounds">
    <item>@drawable/oval1</item>
    <item>@drawable/oval2</item>
    <item>@drawable/oval3</item>
    <item>@drawable/oval4</item>
    <item>@drawable/oval5</item>
</integer-array>
```

Then create special `OnClickListener` class inside your class code

```
private static class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    private int mBackgroundIndex = 0;
    private final TypedArray mBackgrounds;

    public MyClickListener(Context context) {
        mBackgrounds = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.backgrounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mBackgroundIndex++;
        if (mBackgroundIndex >= mBackgrounds.length()) {
            mBackgroundIndex = 0;
        }
        v.setBackgroundResource(mBackgrounds.getResourceId(mBackgroundIndex, 0));
    }

    @Override
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
        mBackgrounds.recycle();
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```

And then set that listener to each button:

```
button1.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
button2.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
button3.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
button4.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
button5.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
```

This should result in the following MainActivity code:

```
package com.example.shadowz.buttononclick;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.TintableBackgroundView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button colorChangeButton;
    private TextView basicText;
    private RelativeLayout background;

    Button button1;
    Button button2;
    Button button3;
    Button button4;
    Button button5;
    Drawable oval1;
    Drawable oval2;
    Drawable oval3;
    Drawable oval4;
    Drawable oval5;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        background = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
        basicText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        colorChangeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

        // Code Break

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        button5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);

        button1.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
        button2.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
        button3.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
        button4.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
        button5.setOnClickListener(new MyClickListener(this));
    }

    private static class MyClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

        private int mBackgroundIndex = 0;
        private final TypedArray mBackgrounds;

        public MyClickListener(Context context) {
            mBackgrounds = context.getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.backgrounds);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mBackgroundIndex++;
            if (mBackgroundIndex >= mBackgrounds.length()) {
                mBackgroundIndex = 0;
            }
            v.setBackgroundResource(mBackgrounds.getResourceId(mBackgroundIndex, 0));
        }

        @Override
        protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
            mBackgrounds.recycle();
            super.finalize();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a little trouble implementing what you have suggested.
I have added the interger-array, but as for the rest, anywhere i put it, it breaks my code. I'm not exactly sure where i need to be editing the code to make what you have suggested work. I have only been coding for just under a week now. But i'm determined to get this to work.

I have added the full MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml if that helps at all

Comment: I've added the code into your MainActivity, please try it. If you will gert some errors please post them into your question body.

Comment: The code works fine, but it just makes all my buttons see through white. It doesn't add extra colors on click. So that seems to be a backwards step to where i was at, since i can get the button from blue to red, and button 2 from blue to green. Is there something like " if this button is red, change color to green, then if this button is green, change color to blue, then if this button is blue, change color to purple, then if this color is purple, go back to start / red. rinse and repeat?

Comment: You need different start colors? But strategy of changing `red->green->blue->purple->red` is common, right?

Comment: The start color will be the same on all buttons. Each button will be an exact copy of each other. So I just need 1 button, to cycle through set colors in a loop. And then I'll just copy that for each other button.

Comment: There was an error in MyClickListener code, i've fixed it. Please try it again.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Now to try and get it to do what I want it to do.